# sqlite3 new version upgrading issue error

Tags: sqlite, centos8

i need to update sqlite3 to new version, so I renamed existing file "sqlite3" to "sqlsql", then copied new file "sqlite3" and run commands below

[root@vkc-vcards-pro-dm bin]# chmod 775 sqlite3
[root@vkc-vcards-pro-dm bin]# ls -la sqlite3
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 root root 987012 Mar 28 20:28 sqlite3

[root@vkc-vcards-pro-dm bin]# sqlite3 --version
bash: /bin/sqlite3: No such file or directory

actually /bin is the shortcut to /usr/bin, but it is not found by commands

[root@vkc-vcards-pro-dm bin]# ls -la /bin | grep sqlite3
[root@vkc-vcards-pro-dm bin]# ls -la /usr/bin | grep sqlite3
-rwxrwxr-x.  1 root root      987012 Mar 28 20:28 sqlite3

but in WINSCP I can see this file /usr/bin

please help me in this issue